# Silex: send more than one route to the same page

Tags: php, routes, silex

I need to match some different routes to aim the same page.

E.g.: / , /inicio, /home -> must show the landing page

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
        return $app['twig']->render(
            'home.html.twig', 
            array(
                'page' => 'home'
            )
        );
    })
    ->bind('home');
```

And I'd like to avoid the same for each route. I'd like to do something like

```
$app->match('/|/home|/inicio, function() use ($app) {} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for this:

```
$app->get("/{slug}", function ($slug) use ($app) {
    // your regular action logic
})->assert("slug", '^(home|inicio)$');
```

[Here's the link to the docs](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#requirements) on route requirements.